# How to add Search bar with edit text in toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to add search bar with edit text in toolbar like below image
[image]

My toolbar.xml:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

After adding edit text in toolbar my toolbar show like this:-

[image]

Comment: your desired image is first one but you are getting second one , actually you want something like first image . am i right?

Comment: ok .. may be i got it ... wait please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

as my understanding I hope this code can help you...

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray_500"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center|right">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center|right">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="snap deal"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="Img"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </TextView>


        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center|right">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMobileNo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/login_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Find your dil ki deal"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search"
                android:gravity="center" >
            </EditText>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

this is custom shape for `EditText login_edittext.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient 
                android:angle="270"
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:startColor="@color/white" />
            <stroke 
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/gray_500" />
            <corners 
                android:radius="1dp" />
            <padding 
                android:bottom="10dp" 
                android:left="10dp" 
                android:right="10dp" 
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

[image]

this is just  sketch... you need to change back color ,size ,image etc.....

Comment: Your android:background="@drawable/login_edittext" can you give me these file

Comment: This work well but search bar override other icon and show top of the toolbar.

Comment: is EditText top of the snap deal ?

Comment: Yes EditText top of snap deal

Comment: How is it possible !!!.. i used linearlayout. did u copied exactly same  code which i have posted..

Comment: wait i provided you sanpshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92959/discussion-between-tanim-reja-and-anand-jain).

Answer (score 11):

I believe the view you are looking for is a `SearchView`. You can define on your `menu.xml` that you want to add it to your ActionBar/ToolBar. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Back on your Activity or Fragment you can manipulate the search view behavior and looks:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
    ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    v.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_icon); //Changing the image

    if (!searchFor.isEmpty()) {
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setQuery(searchFor, false);
    }

    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
          //Do your search
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if(newText.isEmpty()) clearSearch();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

That is a simpler way to do it. The most advised way is to actually have an activity to respond to your search intents. For more info on that behalf visit: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: I am not talking about developing side i just want how to design my toolbar like i given snap deal image

Answer (score 3):

Just add an edit text as part of your toolbar, something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: and how to add search image icon right side of edit text

Comment: add it as a regular item menu.

Comment: your question has completely changed. For what you want now, have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html) link.

Comment: No my question is same i want same search box i given images above

Answer (score 0):

you can directly place the searchview in your activity.xml inside your toolbar and initialize it.I guess you will get the desired layout .

Answer (score 0):

I like the TextEdit solution above for backward compatibility.

Here are two more things to consider to achieve the original example:

1. On the Activity xml TextEdit definition add:

android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"

```
                               // To add the magnifying glass.
```

android:hint="@string/Search_Txt"

```
                              // To add the hint message.
```

2. On the String xml file add:

   string name="Search_Txt">Find your dil ki deal

   ```
                            // Customize your message here.
   ```

Note: The SearchView alternative will require API 21.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Just add either one of this will hide the underline of edit text.

```
android:background="#fff"
```

or

```
android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can follow this code: 

step 1:
make the menu and add an icon :
   <item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search  "
    android:icon="@drawable/search_ic"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
step 2: in adapter file make on create option menu over ride:

 

     override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_option, menu)
            val menuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
            val searchView: SearchView = menuitem.actionView as SearchView
            searchView.queryHint = "Type here to search categories"
    
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
    
                @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
    
    
                    templist.clear()
                    val searcktext = newText!!.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    if (searcktext.isNotEmpty()) {
                        list.forEach {
    
                            if (it.eng_name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                    .contains(searcktext) || it.eng_name.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())
                                    .contains(searcktext)
                            ) {
                                templist.add(it)
                            }
                        }
                        resView2.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    
                    } else {
                        templist.clear()
                        templist.addAll(list)
                        resView2.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
    
                    }
    
                    return false
                }
        })
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        }
```