# How to use searchView inside actionBarStyle?

Tags: android, android-layout

My App style hierarchy is as follows:

```
<style name="MiddleBaseApTheme" parent="@style/BaseAppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:targetApi="11">@style/MainActionBarStyle</item>

<item name="navigationIcon">@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black56</item>

        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MainActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Then, I have defined action bar style as:

```
<style name="MainActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:elevation" tools:targetApi="21">@dimen/action_bar_elevation</item>
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/action_bar_elevation</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/CustomPopup</item>

    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>

</style>
```

This is successfully showing app bar as:

[image]

Now I want to go one step further and trying :

1. To use same style and add a search bar on the existing action bar, I tried using :

`<item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>`

on MiddleBaseTheme, AppTheme.SearchView contain AutoCompleteBox TextView style as:

```
<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextView</item>
</style>
```

But this doesn't show any SearchView on Action bar... Why?

Comment: Where is `@style/AutoCompleteTextView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this question's answer

[How to add Search bar with edit text in toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250875/how-to-add-search-bar-with-edit-text-in-toolbar)