# How to make a Search Bar in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-search

Can i use `editText` as Search bar in android? I am not trying to make a search bar inside a toolbar so i am thinking that `editText` would be fine but i am not sure and that is why i am asking. I have made my research but there is no new content on this topic and the android documentation with the search bar widget is confusing to me. And another question i have is how can i display the data after the request from the search bar is made. Should i display it in the same `fragment` or should i start a new `activity`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873977/4704327 this might help you in your first question 'Can i use editText as Search bar in android?'

Comment: I will give this a read. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use **editText** for searching, but you have to code searching capability manually. You can show search result both in fragment and in activity.

My **Recommendation** is to display it in the **same fragment**.

Comment: But because i already have a recycler view in this fragment, is it ok if i just make when user searches something the od recycler view to be gone and the new one to be shown.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250875/how-to-add-search-bar-with-edit-text-in-toolbar

Comment: adapter attached only recyclerView part of XML

Comment: you can add anything in that layout